# How to changing WebSphere Application Server datasource URL by wsadmin?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

Is possible to change Websphere datasource IP address? I've tried this script but it doesn't work

```
def updateDataSourceIP(newIP):
    datasources = AdminConfig.getid('/DataSource:/').splitlines()
      for datasource in datasources:
    propertySet = AdminConfig.showAttribute(t1, 'propertySet')
    propertyList = AdminConfig.list('J2EEResourceProperty', propertySet).splitlines()
    for prop in propertyList:
      if (AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'name') == 'serverName'):
        oldip = AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'value')
        print "Updating serverName attribute of datasource '" + datasource + "' from " + oldip + " to " + sys.argv[0]
        AdminConfig.modify(prop, '[[value ' + newIP + ']]')
        AdminConfig.reset();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, you are using

```
AdminConfig.reset()
```

at the end of the script, which discards all changes.  Try switching to

```
AdminConfig.save()
```